# Что за плагин, позволяющий, к примеру, в HTML задавать структуру элемента в одну строку?

Tags: html

Вместо того, чтобы прописывать вручную неотсортированный список с шестью элементами и классом `flex-elem` в каждой `<li>`, умные люди пишут: `ul.flex-cont>li.flex-elem{elem-$}*6` + ввод. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это за плагин.

Answer (score 3):

Плагин Emmet:
[Emmet](https://emmet.io)

Список поддерживаемых редакторов: [Список редакторов](https://emmet.io/download/)